# Is possible to detect ANDROID NDK_TOOLCHAIN versions by minor and patchlevel?

Tags: android, c++, macros, android-ndk, toolchain

I want to detect and store information about used compiler and version which did a binary built via macros detection. For example like GCC has macros for **GNUC** (major version) **GNUC_MINOR** (minor version) and **GNUC_PATCHLEVEL**. Is this possible with Android NDK?? to detect exactly which version of compiler was used for building shared library?

Comment: If your ndk uses GCC, these will be defined

Answer (score 0):

In your Android.mk, you could add a custom build step that would dump whatever environment information into some text file. This file could be embedded in your APK, or even in the compiled obj file.

Would this be an acceptable solution?